# Is it possible to fatch each data in single loop and store in respective array?

Tags: python-2.7

Extracting data from xml file usesing python. Is it possible to fatch each data in single loop and store in respective array?

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as etree
xmlDoc = open('C:/Users/Talha/Documents/abc.xml', 'r')
xmlDocData = xmlDoc.read()
xmlDocTree = etree.XML(xmlDocData)
srnoList, stateList, statecdList, districtList, issuedOnList, dayList, normalRainfallList, normalTempmaxList, normalTempminList = ([] for i in range(9)) 

for srno in xmlDocTree.iter('Srno'):
    srnoList.append(srno.text)
for state in xmlDocTree.iter('State'):
    stateList.append(state.text)
for statecd in xmlDocTree.iter('Statecd'):
    statecdList.append(statecd.text)
for district in xmlDocTree.iter('District'):
    districtList.append(district.text)
for issuedOn in xmlDocTree.iter('IssuedOn'):
    issuedOnList.append(issuedOn.text)
for day in xmlDocTree.iter('Day'):
    dayList.append(day.text)
for normalRainfall in xmlDocTree.iter('normal_rainfall'):
    normalRainfallList.append(normalRainfall.text)
for normalTempmax in xmlDocTree.iter('normal_temp_max'):
    normalTempmaxList.append(normalTempmax.text)
for normalTempmin in xmlDocTree.iter('normal_temp_min'):
    normalTempminList.append(normalTempmin.text)
```

Comment: What does your XML look like?

Comment: http://farmer.gov.in/ForecastService.asmx/forecastservice?date=19-07-2017                                                                                                                            Click on this link you will get it know how xml file look like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Down to 2 loops, but a lot cleaner:

```
sections = ['Srno','State','Statecd','District','IssuedOn','Day','normal_rainfall','normal_temp_max','normal_temp_min']
fetched = dict()
for sec in sections:
    fetched[sec] = []
    for item in xmlDocTree.iter( sec ):
        fetched[sec].append( item )
```

Instead of distinct variables for each type of data, each is an item in a dictionary.  This could be tweaked to use different keys for the dictionary.